# Use external class in drupal 8 module with file name and class name

Tags: drupal-8

I create a module in drupal 8 .
I want using a class in external class file .

File name : drupal.php

Class name : class newman{...}

In drupal.php :

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\mymodulename\lib;
class newman{
   public function new(){
       $dp = 'TEST';
       return $dp;
   }
}
?>
```

In my contoller :

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\mymodulename\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\mymodulename\lib\drupal;

class mmController extends ControllerBase {
    public function man() {
          $this->man=new newman();
          $build['test'] = [
                            '#markup' => $man->new(),
                           ];
    }
}
```

Error: Class 'Drupal\mymodulename\Controller\newman' not found in Drupal...

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

create your class file as field plugin

```
moduleName/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/NewMan.php
```

file name and class name should be same

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\moduleName\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter;


class NewMan {
  //class content
}
```

then use it any where

```
//include file
use Drupal\moduleName\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\NewMan;
// use
$newMan =new NewMan();
```

Hope this solve your problem
Dont forget to mark as answers if this solve your problem thanks.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In the drupal.php file, which should be renamed to Newman.php (Coding standards), Also remove the closing PHP tag here.

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\mymodulename\lib;

class Newman {
 public function new(){
   $dp = 'TEST';
   return $dp;
 }
}
```

In your controller

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\mymodulename\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\mymodulename\lib\Newman;

class mmController extends ControllerBase {
  public function man() {
    $man = new Newman();

    $build['test'] = [
       '#markup' => $man->new(),
    ];
  }
}
```